# Equivalent of yield return of C# in delphi

Tags: c#, delphi, delphi-2010

I am converting a C# code into Delphi 2010.I am stuck on finding an equivalent of yield return of C# in delphi.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is simply no equivalent. Delphi does not have any matching functionality. In C# `yield return` is used in C# iterator methods, and Delphi does not have anything remotely like C# iterator methods.

In Delphi you need to write iterators manually, without the syntactic sugar of iterator methods. This is described in the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declarations_and_Statements#Iteration_Over_Containers_Using_For_statements).

Answer (score 3):

There are at least two implementations of Yield in delphi (both not ideal, though).

First is using asm magic, here: http://santonov.blogspot.ru/2007/10/yield-you.html

Second is using Win32 fibers(very lightweight threads), so will work only on windows. It's here: http://www.gerixsoft.com/blog/delphi/yield

There is one more, slightly less readable, implementation based on fibers: http://delphisorcery.blogspot.ru/2011/04/yield-return-and-delphi.html

That said, i won't recommend using yield if you are new with Delphi, because it is not common way of programming in Delphi. So use it only if you understand consequences.

Comment: The second implementation is based on the third one. Perhaps @StefanGlienke can add more information about implications using the second one.

Answer (score 1):

There is coroutine based framework for Delphi https://github.com/Purik/AIO

You can see example of generator (like in Python) here - https://github.com/Purik/AIO/blob/master/Demos/Tutorial/Generator.dpr